# $p(x) = x^3 - 2x^2 + 4x - 8$ and $x = 2$ is a $0$, use synthetic division to obtain factorization of $p(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is what I have, and I would like to get it verified.

$$p(2) = 0 = x^3 - 2x^2 + 4x - 8\\
  \frac{(x - 2)} {(x^3 - 2x^2 + 4x - 8)}\\
    x^2 + 4 = x^3 - 2x^2 + 4x - 8$$

I think the synthetic division answer is $(x^2 + 4)$

1. Is this correct?
2. How do I take this to identify other solutions?

I need to factor the polynomial using synthetic division then I need to identify other solutions of $p(x) = 0$.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

You can use synthetic division, or simply use inspection, to find that
$$
(x^3-2x^2+4x-8)=(x-2)(x^2+4) \, .
$$
Notice how the parabola with the equation $y=x^2+4$ does not touch the $x$-axis:

[image: Graph of y=x^2+4]

Hence, the equation $x^2+4=0$ has no real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you factor is correct.

$x^3 - 2x^2 + 4x - 8 = (x-2)(x^2+4)$

Solutions for

$p(x) = 0$

$(x-2)(x^2+4) = 0$

$(x-2) = 0 \Rightarrow x=2$

$x^2+4 = 0 \Rightarrow x^2 = -4  \Rightarrow x = 2i ,x =-2i$

So three roots are $2,2i,-2i$